# Netflix doesn't work since installing Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: firefox, 18.04, netflix

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 64-bit and enabled DRM in Firefox. When trying to watch Netflix, I get the following errors:

```
Oops, something went wrong...

Netflix video player unavailable

We're having trouble playing Netflix in your browser. Please make sure you're on an official version of Firefox.

Error Code: F7355-1204
```

I'm using the version of Firefox that came installed with Ubuntu. How do I play Netflix videos on 18.04?

Comment: Do you have Adobe Flash? Can you watch videos from Facebook?

Comment: In theory you should already be able to do so. If no one comes up with a better answer you could try reinstalling firefox, but I'd wait to see if someone has a less drastic solution.

Comment: I don't have Flash and didn't have in 17.10, but in 17.10 Netflix worked.

Comment: @SebastianStark That fixed the issue, thanks! Please post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In order to watch netflix with firefox under Ubuntu 18.04, you need to make sure that you have DRM enabled in your firefox settings (Go to *settings*, scroll down, check *play drm-controlled content*). Also make sure you have the `libavcodec-extra` package (from the *universe* repository) installed. In order to install libavcodec-extra you should have the *universe* repository enabled:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Then install the libavcodec-extra package:

```
sudo apt install libavcodec-extra
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this fix at [Netflix support site](https://help.netflix.com/en/node/23742). I have the HTML 5 theme enabled and Silverlight theme was also added but not enabled.

I also have the following plugins enabled, OpenH264 Video Codec, shockwave flash, and Widevine Content Decryption Module.

Netflix is now working perfectly from Firefox browser in Ubuntu 18.04.