# Netflix not working on Firefox 60.0.1 64-bit on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: firefox, 18.04, netflix

Brand new Ubuntu 18.04 install. Opened included Firefox 60.0.1 64-bit and logged into Netflix. `Error F7355`. Not `F7355-1203`, `F7355-1204` or `F7355`-anything else. Just `F7355`.

```
DRM-controlled content is enabled.  
OpenH264 is installed and enabled.  
Widevine is installed and enabled.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: ...and of course, I've restarted both browser and computer and tried again without luck.

Comment: have you tried the Netflix troubleshooting: https://help.netflix.com/en/node/85?ui_action=kb-article-popular-categories

Comment: No, I hadn't seen that page. But all it does is suggest I make sure I have an internet connection. Which I obviously have. But thanks anyway :-)

Comment: well, it also asks you to reset your router back to factory settings if you've customised in anyway, and also suggests contacting the ISP that supplied the equipment as they may also be able to assist. Netflix themselves also have support phone and messaging folks... that direction may well be quicker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the answer here:
[Netflix doesn't work since installing Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030432/netflix-doesnt-work-since-installing-ubuntu-18-04?rq=1)

This solution worked for me:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt install libavcodec-extra
```

I've also been told that

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

will solve this problem, but I haven't tried that yet.

Comment: I don't want to delete my question, because a popup warns me that I might be blocked for it! So I will instead edit my answer to include the solution from the link.

Comment: If your answer is essentially a referral to another question, it would be better to [flag](/help/privileges/flag-posts) this question as a duplicate of the other once you [earned 15 reputation](/help/whats-reputation). If you have the reputation don’t forget to vote for the answer(s) there that you found useful!

Comment: Six users have currently flagged this question as a duplicate. I can't flag it as a duplicate directly, but I can request that a moderator take a look at it. Would this make sense, or should I just leave it at that?

Comment: Looks like somebody was faster with their flag for the same duplicate target than you and there's no need to flag any more. (The users who voted to close the question as a duplicate are [reviewers who earned the "cast close vote" privilege](/help/privileges/close-questions), as opposed to [our elected moderators bestowed with super-powers](/help/site-moderators).)

Comment: I only had to install `ubuntu-restricted-extras` to get it working!