# Netflix not working in neither Chrome, Firefox or Opera, on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, firefox, google-chrome, netflix, opera

The title is pretty self explanatory, but I'll try to write as many details as possible, because this problem has been driving me nuts for the past few hours.

Yesterday, I installed **18.04.2 LTS** on my personal computer, the minimal version.

Today, I tried accessing Netflix using Google Chrome, **version 72.0.3626.121 (Official Build) (64-bit)** and Firefox, **version 65.0.1 (64-bit)**.

However, no matter what I do, I keep getting this error:

> Netflix Site Error. We were unable to process your request. Please go to the Netflix home page by clicking the button below.

Obviously, I did my best to search this issue and found a few answers, which unfortunately, did not fixed my problem.

Here are the things that I've tried:

- DRM is enabled in my Firefox settings
- I have installed the **libavcodec-extra** package through the commands provided here: [Netflix doesn't work since installing Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030432/netflix-doesnt-work-since-installing-ubuntu-18-04)
- I have installed the **ubuntu-restricted-extras** package as suggested here: [Netflix not working on Firefox 60.0.1 64-bit on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042947/netflix-not-working-on-firefox-60-0-1-64-bit-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts)

As far as I know, Netflix should work natively on Google Chrome. In my case, it doesn't. As I was writing, I quickly installed Opera and tried accessing Netflix, but ran into the same issue.

I'm running out of ideas. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Later edit**
After some updates, Netflix has started working again. No idea why though or if the updates had anything to do with it.

Comment: It's probably a Netflix problem... but you can try this... boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, install Chrome, try Netflix. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema, thanks for the suggestion, but for some reason, this issue has been resolved. Yesterday, after receiving a couple of updates (including core), Netflix started working again on all browsers.

Comment: You may answer your own question and accept it to get this marked as "solved".

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced a similar issue after I upgraded to Ubuntu 19.10.
To solve this, try running this command via terminal:

```
sudo apt install libavcodec-extra
```

After this, reboot the system and try running Netflix on any browser.