# Netflix not working on Ubuntu 19.10 with Chromium

Tags: 19.10, chromium, netflix

I have not much do add to the title, for some reason works with Firefox but not with Chromium and I would like to fix it. I searched on the web and seems I'm not the only one but found not good answer, not one at least that fixed my problem.
I red that could be something related to DRM content reproduction on the browse.
I red [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1124835/netflix-not-working-in-neither-chrome-firefox-or-opera-on-ubuntu-18-04?newreg=c369897c5fcc455b92a93e32cdc36a18) question but no solution for me.

Comment: Read my comment that I left under the first answer. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: It's possible to do. I've described it on Linux Mint forum: forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=315627. Unfortunately all questions here on askubuntu are being closed with links to old/obsolete questions/answers that doesn't fix the problem. In short: go to chrome://components, update Widevine, restart chromium, install some user agent switcher and add e.g. firefox's user agent and set it to be permanently used on netflix.com.

Answer (score 3):

Chromium doesn't bundle the required DRM modules for Netflix to work. This has nothing to do with the question you linked. Netflix just doesn't work with Chromium. Only Firefox and Google Chrome are supported.

Comment: Yes, I red that, but I also saw someone saying that there are a couple of ways to let Chromium play DRM content, there are pages like [this](https://www.andreafortuna.org/2019/09/24/how-to-install-latest-widevine-plugin-on-chromium/) that say you need to download Widevine to solve the problem and someone say it helped, but unfortunately not for me, maybe I've done something wrong? In any case, I think it's impossible that there is no way I can watch Netflix on Chromium...or at least it's really hard to belive...

Comment: Yep, it appears in the past you could hack Chromium by copying the widevine lib over, but an update broke that.

Comment: Ah..so it is no more the case? Now no way to view Netflix on Chromium? So should I give up?

Comment: The method that worked in the past doesn't work any more. Currently there is no way to get widevine working in Chromium that I know of. I'd say, just use Chrome. :)

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for the interest. I will leave the thread open in hope someone will come out with some new hack or cool way to do it!