# Why does Firefox need libavcodec-extra for displaying Netflix videos?

Tags: 18.04, firefox, dependencies, netflix

Recently I had issues watching Netflix on Firefox.
[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030432/netflix-doesnt-work-since-installing-ubuntu-18-04) solved it.

Why does Firefox need it?
Why didn't it show an error message saying that the library was not found?

Comment: I think questions about the internal workings of FireFox are best directed to that community and not the Ask Ubuntu community.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I thought this was Ubuntu related because it does not happen on Windows...

Comment: Fair enough. I upvoted your question as a new user to get some points. Beware your question might get closed as off topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netflix relies on DRM (Digital Rights Management) mechanisms to provide content legally. Most Studios insist on using such Technologies, while Linux is a completly opposite idea of how technology should work and be shared.

Since this discrepancy between FOSS communities and Industry interests, libs with such technologies are marked as "ugly", "extra" or "restricted" and not installed by default, since the majority of linux users despise such libraries and choose to not install them and would be pretty upset if the would install by default.

This is a result of the ever ongoing war between open knowledge and closed knowledge. Choose your side.

Hope this helps understanding.

Comment: That's very helpful. Now, what about Firefox not showing an error? Would that be offtopic to this community?

Comment: "Why didn't it show an error message saying that the library was not found? " because it is netflix that catches the error and shows in in-site message.

Comment: I second what Rinzwind says: It is not firefox missing the library, but the netflix player.